# How to make Python var='\\x' + "FF" as 1 byte?

Tags: python, hex

sample code:

```
hexVar = '1D' # i need this to be dynamically allocated
var1 = '\\x' + hexVar
print "var1 len: ", len(var1) # gives me 4 instead of 1
```

i need this var1 to be 1 byte when sending to a socks udp associate request format

Comment: convert string to `integer` and then to `chr()` and you can encode to single `bytes` with code `b"\x1d"` which you can send in socket

Answer (score 0):

You can convert text to integer (with base 16), next integer to char, and char encode to single byte with code `b"\x1d"`

```
hexVar = '1D'
integer = int(hexVar, 16)
char = chr(integer)
var1 = char.encode()
print("var1 len: ", len(var1), var1) #
```

Result

```
var1 len:  1 b'\x1d'
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
import binascii

hexVar = '1D'
var1 = binascii.a2b_hex(hexVar)

print("var1 len: ", len(var1), var1)
```

or

```
import binascii

hexVar = '1D'
var1 = binascii.unhexlify(hexVar)

print("var1 len: ", len(var1), var1)
```